# Trouble importing pygame module using python 3.2.2

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to get the pygame module to work with python3 in a macbook 10.6. I read it was tricky, I had to install from source code following these instructions: http://programming.itcarlow.ie/PyGameInstall.pdf Everything went OK, but when I try to import pygame I get this error:

```
Python 3.2.2 (v3.2.2:137e45f15c0b, Sep  3 2011, 17:28:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_base)
```

I have no idea what this means. I have done the regular installation and it works fine with python 2.7 but I want some features from python3. Any ideas about what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this question because I was faced with the same challenge. I discovered that Python 3.2.x has a bug with pygame package. I wanted Python 3.x with pygame. I uninstalled Python 3.2.3 and reinstalled Python 3.1.4 then installed pygame-1.91.win32-py3.1.msi and it now works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.x series is not retro-compatible with 2.x series; thus you need the specific pygame version for Python 3.x (or run it through 2_to_3 script, although I'm not sure it works on C code too..). Why don't you want to use Python 2.7?

Comment: I know that, that's why I used those instructions, the're specific on  how to make pygame work under python 3.x on a macbook running 10.6. I figured since I was using the source code I did not need a special binary code for mac or for python 3.x. What I don't understand is the last line on the error message.

Comment: From the swig doc here http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn9 it looks like usually it is a `.so` naming error..

Comment: That actually helps a little, but still no .so file naming was up to me during the installation so I still have no idea how to fix this.